# NFA or DFA accepting # of positions of 4k between 0's

Tags: automata, finite-automata, dfa, nfa, automata-theory

[image]

Left is the given solution, but it fails for 01110(shouldn't be true) and 010000 (should be true). If we do it like the right one like I did, then there might not be 1 in it so it fails because 000000 shouldn't be in it, how do I manage to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From context, I think "separated by a number of positions that is a multiple of four" must mean that the number of things between the 0s must have a length that's a multiple of four, rather than the positions of two 0s differing by four. So, 011110 would be a string in the language, rather than 01110, since there are four 1s between the 0s in the first case, rather than 4 - 0 = 4 in the second case.

Given that, I agree the NFA on the left is incorrect: it accepts 01110 when it should not.

Note though that 000000 should be accepted, in particular, because:

- the substring 00 has zero symbols between the two 0s and zero is a multiple of four
- the string 000000 can be written 0(0000)0 and it's clear there are four 0s between the 0s on the ends, and four is a multiple of four

The NFA on the right seems correct since:

- it can deal with any prefix by looping on the initial state
- it can see 0 when it needs to
- it can see another 0 immediately afterwards or else any number of symbols, four at a time, and then a following 0
- it can deal with any suffix by looping on the final state

Comment: I agree with your reasoning, but one small remark: The FA on the left side is a NFA not a DFA because there are two possible transitions for `0` in the initial state

Comment: @derpirscher Yep you are of course correct, edited.